# How to Group and Include all Categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to take my raw data and group it by Name but show all the categories that each name is associated with. Hopefully the picture simplifies what I'm trying to do.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  I have considered making a pivot and then combining columns somehow, but I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward and simpler way.  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FOR XML PATH` to build your CSV string. The `STUFF` simply removes the leading comma from the list.

```
SELECT Name, Categories = STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + Category 
        FROM dbo.YourTable
        WHERE Name = x.Name
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM dbo.YourTable AS x
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: I'm going to have to step through that carefully.  I'm not familiar with the Stuff function or XML Path.  Thanks for setting me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

You can use stuff and xml path as below:

```
Select [Name], 
    Categories = stuff((select Concat(',',category) from #rawdata r where r.[Name] = ou.[Name] for xml path('')), 1,1, '')
from #rawdata ou group by [Name]
```

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or SQL Azure then you can use String_Agg as below

```
Select [Name], String_Agg(category,',') from #rawdata
   group by [Name]
```

Comment: I'm going to have to step through that carefully.  I'm not familiar with the Stuff function or XML Path.  Thanks for setting me on the right track!  Looks like you and Joe provided very similar answers.  I will look carefully at them both.